# Web API 2 response type comparison

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I had coded like this, it is good for unit testing.

```
[ResponseType(typeof(bool))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Send()
{
    try
    {
        await dosomething();

        return Ok(true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return InternalServerError(ex);
    }
}
```

But someone suggested the try catch is redundant because Web API handles that already, and he proposed this code:

```
public async Task<bool> Send()
{
    await dosomething();

    return true;
}
```

I just want to know which one is better choice.

Comment: With Async programming like this, i would suggest the first option is best for when you need to debug your work and catch exceptions. Web API does not handle this automatically, i wouldn't agree with that. Try throwing exception in both cases to test it.

Comment: I think additional try catch will cause it to do more work in terms of performance, if there was an exception it will be caught here and won't propagate to the Web API global level. I guess Web API already handles uncaught exceptions so that error 500 will still be returned. Anyway I will try to produce an exception and check it out. Thanks

Comment: I'm merely talking about when you have to debug faults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a read of [Exception Handling in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling)

> What happens if a Web API controller throws an uncaught exception? By
>   default, most exceptions are translated into an HTTP response with
>   status code 500, Internal Server Error.

and also [Global Error Handling in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling)

As for the mentioned suggestion proposed, you should try to keep your controller lean as much as possible. Error handling like your original code will only result in duplication of code, and unnecessary concerns for the developers to be aware of. Developers should focus on the core-concern, not the cross-cutting concerns. By just focusing on the core-concern the above code will look like this:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(bool))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Send() {
    await dosomething();
    return Ok(true);
}
```

Error handling in Web API is considered a cross-cutting concern and should be placed somewhere else in the pipeline so the developers doesn’t need to focus on cross-cutting concerns.

Comment: I have just realised there is an exception handler registered in the Web API config, hence the try catch is redundant.Thanks for your help!